# How to find Git in android studio version control?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

all
I do not find git choice in android studio 'File-Settings-Version Control', I searched for so long that many guys could find 'Git' there, but I can't, how can I do? I use android studio 3.1.3, and this is my settings picture, should I click add? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgzzU.png)

Comment: Is the git integration plugin activated?

Comment: sorry, I don't know is that the git integration plugin activated, how can I find out?